# null is not an object (evaluating 'date.toDateString) using @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Tags: react-native

```
I want validation using @react-native-community/datetimepicker But i got this error,
How to fix it?
```

I am trying to implement validation using datetimepicker, but how to set null as default how to do this, pls help and thanks in advance.

```
export default function demo() {
  const [datePicker, setDatePicker] = useState(false);

  const [date, setDate] = useState(null);

  console.log("Null is =============>");

  if (date === null) {
    console.log("Please enter date");
  }

  function showDatePicker() {
    setDatePicker(true);
  }

  function onDateSelected(event, value) {
    setDate(value);
    setDatePicker(false);
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styleSheet.MainContainer}>
        <TextInput
          value={date.toDateString()}
          placeholder={"12/34/2023"}
        ></TextInput>

        {datePicker && (
          <DateTimePicker
            value={date}
            mode={"date"}
            display={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "spinner" : "default"}
            is24Hour={true}
            onChange={onDateSelected}
            style={styleSheet.datePicker}
          />
        )}

    I am trying to implement validation using datetimepicker, but how to set null as default how to do this, pls help and thanks in advance.
```

How to fix this error
null is not an object (evaluating 'date.toDateString) using @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Comment: Have you tried `date.dateString`?

Comment: When I used date. dateString i got null is not an object (evaluating 'date.dateString) . I want simple put validation when user not select date

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from  **coalescing operator (??)** . Link for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing

Also, if you want to perform validation, do it on some button click or form submission. This way it would be easy to catch null values.

For now, if we show warning as text, code can be as :

```
      <TextInput
        value={date?.toDateString() ?? ''}
        placeholder={'Enter Date MM/DD/YYYY'}
        onFocus={() => {
          showDatePicker();
        }}></TextInput>

      {date == null && <Text>Please enter date</Text>}

      {datePicker && (
        <DateTimePicker
          value={date ?? new Date()}
          mode={'date'}
          display={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'spinner' : 'default'}
          is24Hour={true}
          onChange={onDateSelected}
        />
      )}
```

Comment: I add your code but error not display and in starting when user not select any date text value not empty instead display today date which is wrong??

Comment: [link](https://snack.expo.dev/@hamza64479/overflow1) snack link for code. 
datepicker module requires a Date or time value by default. It is mandatory. 
We cannot pass empty string or null into "value" attribute. So providing today date as initial value is most feasible.